# In how many ways can we make groups of 3 numbers if we have 4?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So let's say we have $a,b,c,d$. In how many ways we can combine them in groups of 3. For example: $abc,acb,bca,aab,aac,bbc,ddc,ddd,aaa$. There should be a formula using arrangements. I did it long ago and I got like 64 if I remember well. By the ways the numbers can repeat 2 times or 3 times ex.:$aab,ccd,ccc$.

Comment: The number of ways to make three independent choices of 1 letter out of 4 is $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4$.

Comment: So It is 64? Are you sure? Also can you tell me why it is like that?

Comment: Yes, and I explained why if you carefully read the comment.

Comment: http://www.emathematics.net/combinavrepeticion.php

Comment: Ok but I want a math explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [permutations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition), where in your particular case, the set is $S=\{a,b,c,d\}$, i.e. is a $(K=4)$-element set, and you are forming $(n=3)$-tuples.

The answer is, therefore $K^n=4^3.$